# HTML inside of a JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create 10 radio buttons, labeled 1-10 with a for loop inside of my html and I can't get it to work.

```
<html>
    <body>
      <h2 style="text-align:center">
        On a scale from 1-10, how likely are you to recommend this site to a friend or colleague?
      </h2>
        <form id="NPSform"; style= "text-align:center">
            <script>
                for (var i = 1; i <=10; i++) {
                    <input type="radio" name="scores" id="i" value="i"> i
                }
            </script>
            <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks. I'm new to JS so I'm still learning a lot.

Comment: JS isn't like PHP. You can't write directly to the markup, you have to go through the DOM using either the `document` object or using a library like jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add all inputs to one string inside loop and then append it to HTML, also you should separate your `js` and `html` code

```js
var inputs = '';
 for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   inputs += '<input name="scores" type="radio" value="' + i + '" id="' + i + '">'+i+'';
 }
 document.getElementById('NPSform').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', inputs);
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">On a scale from 1-10, how likely are you to recommend this site to a friend or colleague?</h2>
<form id="NPSform" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

You can also create one div, set `innerHTML` and use `insertBefore` to add it to html

```js
var inputs = '';
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  inputs += '<input name="scores" type="radio" value="' + i + '" id="' + i + '">' + i + '';
}

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = inputs;

var submit = document.querySelector('#NPSform input');
submit.parentNode.insertBefore(div, submit);
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">On a scale from 1-10, how likely are you to recommend this site to a friend or colleague?</h2>
<form id="NPSform" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Should you specify the script tag should be placed at the end of the body or at least somewhere outside the form?

Answer (score 6):

Use `document.write` to output the HTML like so.

```
document.write('<input type="radio" name="scores" id="i" value="i"> i');
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
      <h2 style="text-align:center">
        On a scale from 1-10, how likely are you to recommend this site to a friend or colleague?
      </h2>
        <form id="NPSform"; style= "text-align:center">
            <script>
                for (var i = 1; i <=10; i++) {
                    document.write('<input type="radio" name="scores" id="i" value="i">'+ i);
                }
            </script>
            <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: end of the document.write line should read `value="i"> ' + i);`

Comment: Thank you, I knew I missed something!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  function addbuttons() {
    var buttons = document.getElementById("dynamicButtons");
            for (var i = 1; i <=10; i++) {
                buttons.innerHTML += '<input type="radio" name="scores" id="' +i +' " value="' +i +'">'
            }

            }
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="addbuttons()">
  <h2 style="text-align:center">
    On a scale from 1-10, how likely are you to recommend this site to a friend or colleague?
  </h2>
    <form id="NPSform"; style= "text-align:center">     
        <div id="dynamicButtons"></div>
        <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <body>
      <h2 style="text-align:center">
        On a scale from 1-10, how likely are you to recommend this site to a friend or colleague?
      </h2>
        <form id="NPSform"; style= "text-align:center">
            <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
    <script>
        for (var i = 1; i <=10; i++) {
            document.write("<input type='radio' name='scores' id='"+i+"' value='"+i+"'> "+i+"");
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you to improve your example by reading the [Minimal, Complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
    <body>
      <h2 style="text-align:center">
        On a scale from 1-10, how likely are you to recommend this site to a friend or colleague?
      </h2>
      <form id="NPSform"; style= "text-align:center">

        <div id="radioscontainer">
        </div>

        <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>


<script>
  var radioButtons = '';
  for (var i = 1; i <=10; i++) {
    radioButtons += '<input type="radio" name="scores" id="i" value="i"> i';
  }//for
  $("#radioscontainer").append( radioButtons );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He might need a pure js approach instead of jQuery